# “Error: invalid types ‘char[int]’ for array subscript” while trying to access an array with the keypad input

Tags: arrays, types, arduino

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
const int ROW_NUM = 4; //four rows
const int COLUMN_NUM = 4; //four columns
int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
IRsend irsend;
int A[] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
int B[] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
int C[] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
int D[] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};

char keys[ROW_NUM][COLUMN_NUM] = {
  {'1','2','3', 'A'},
  {'4','5','6', 'B'},
  {'7','8','9', 'C'},
  {'*','0','#', 'D'}
};

byte pin_rows[ROW_NUM] = {2, 3, 4, 5}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte pin_column[COLUMN_NUM] = {6, 7, 8, 9}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), pin_rows, pin_column, ROW_NUM, COLUMN_NUM );

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop(){
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key == "#"){
    irsend.sendRC5(0x0, 8); //send 0x0 code (8 bits)
    delay(200);
    irsend.sendRC5(0x1, 8); 
    delay(200); 
    char array_choice = keypad.getKey();
    if (array_choice == "A") {
      int selected_array = A;
      int index_of_signal = keypad.getKey();
      if (index_of_signal == 0) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 1) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 2) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 3) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 4) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 5) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 6) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 7) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 8) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 9) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      }
    if (array_choice == "B") {
      int selected_array == B;
      int index_of_signal = keypad.getKey();
      if (index_of_signal == 0) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 1) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 2) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 3) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 4) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 5) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 6) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 7) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 8) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      if (index_of_signal == 9) {
        irsend.sendRC5(selected_array[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
      }
    }
    if (key == "*") {
      if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
      Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
      irrecv.resume();
      }
  }
}
```

This code is for a universal IR remote, it's supposed to get the value of the IR signal in the selected array and transmit the signal.

Yet when I try to get the keypad input to select the array the user would like to use, I get the error mentioned in the title. I know that my mistake is that the keypad is storing the selection as a char, because of that, it is unable to recognise that the input is supposed to select a specific array and access it. I heard that it might be impossible to get the variables with their stored arrays this way so if you have any ideas on how else to do it, please say so.

How would I go about fixing this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit1: I tried substituting selected_array with the array itself such as:

```
if (index_of_signal == 1) {
        irsend.sendRC5(A[index_of_signal], 8);
        }
```

Yet the error I am getting now is error compiling for Arduino uno board, yet it doesn't point to a specific error in the code.

Comment: `"B"` is not a character. It is a string with one character. If you want to compare `array_choice` to the character `B` then use single quotes: `'B'`.

Comment: As an aside you don't have to check each index since they are on order. Replace your list of `if` statements with just one, `if (index_of_dignal >= 0 && index_of_signal <= 9) ...`

Comment: I did what you said yet I keep on getting the error: "Error compiling for board Arduino Uno" and yet it doesn't indicate what is wrong in my code.

Comment: `int selected_array = A;`  A is not an int, it is an array of ints (a pointer to the first int), so you should declare it as `int *selected_array = A;`

Comment: I don't see any sign in your updated question that you did what I said at all. I still see, for example, `if (array_choice == "B") {` which should be, `if (array_choice == 'B') {` per my first comment.